# In Godaddy,Bulk SMS sending stops in middle

Tags: php

In Godaddy,Bulk SMS sending stops in middle and gives internal server error.. i m trying to send bulk for 600 peoples but sms is sending only for approx 100 peoples and then it shows internal server error

if($_REQUEST['modfunc']=='save')

{

```
foreach($_REQUEST['people'] as $people_id=>$yes)


{
```

$user1=mysql_query("select smsuser from gold where id='".Usergold()."'");

```
        $user2=mysql_fetch_row($user1);

        $user=$user2[0];
```

$pwd1=mysql_query("select smspwd from gold where id='".Usergold()."'");

```
        $pwd2=mysql_fetch_row($pwd1);

        $pwd=$pwd2[0];
```

$send1=mysql_query("select senderid from gold where id='".Usergold()."'");

```
        $send2=mysql_fetch_row($send1);

        $sender=$send2[0];


        $xyz=mysql_query("select phone from people where people_id='$people_id'");

        $xyz2=mysql_fetch_row($xyz);

        $pno=$xyz2[0];
```

// create a new cURL resource

$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://xxxxxx.com/api/sendmsg.php?user=$user&pass=$pwd&sender=$sender&phone=$pno&text=".urlencode($_REQUEST['MESSAGE'])."&priority=ndnd&stype=normal");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

```
}
unset($_REQUEST['modfunc']);

$note = _("SMS is sent to the selected people.");
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sending bulk sms stops in middle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043572/sending-bulk-sms-stops-in-middle)

Comment: hi HPierce .... even there also not have working answer...

Comment: You should update your question to explain that - as it stands currently, the linked question appears to be _exactly_ what you're describing and has an accepted answer. We're happy to help you further, but we're going to need more information. An HTTP 500 error is just about a vague as it gets when it comes to error messages. Can we see more of your code?

Comment: Mr.HPierce.. i have edited the coding.. can u pls check it now and find solutio...

Comment: Please check your ini script to check for maximum execution time. Generally it is set to 30 Secs. Anything more than 30 hangs up. So increase it manually